# Name "window" is not defined error is coming while executing the mentioned code

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, customtkinter, new-window

Name "window" is not defined error is coming while executing the mentioned code

```py
def create_window():
    window = ctk.CTk()
    window.title("CREATE")
    window.geometry("1789x760")

create_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(window, width=600, height=300)
create_frame.pack()

create_label = ctk.CTkLabel(create_frame, text="Sample")
create_label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `window` is a local variable in `create_window`. It will not be available outside of that function.

Comment: Should all the code be inside `create_window()`?

Comment: window = ctk.CTk()
    def create_window():

Comment: @Great Ideas. See screenshot. https://ibb.co/p25hqmm

Answer (score 0):

You could try this functional approach:

```
def populate_window(root_window):
    create_frame = ctk.CTk.Frame(root_window, width=600, height=300)
    create_frame.pack()
    create_label = ctk.CTkLabel(create_frame, text="Sample")
    create_label.pack()

window = ctk.CTk()
window.title('CREATE')
window.geometry('1789x760')
window.mainloop()
```

This would work, however, you would not be able to reuse the `populate_window` function easily.

This Object Oriented approach would allow for more portability and code reuse:

```
class Window(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        ctk.CTkFrame.__init__(self, self.parent)
        self.pack()
        self.populate_window()

    def populate_window(self):
        create_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Sample")
        create_label.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = ctk.CTk()
    root.title("CREATE")
    root.geometry('1789x760')
    window = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello @Carson Miller,
I have the below my full code for which I need solution, so could you please help me on this